# Checking how long a user has been logged in

Tags: linux, users, login, time

Is it possible to check for how long a user has been logged in? Or when the user logged in on an Unix/Linux system?

I logged in as another user on my system a while ago and I would like to now how long that user has been logged in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `last` you can find this information.  The following may be useful:

```
last <username> | less
```

It will return something like this:

```
benlavery@Talantinc:bin $>last benlavery | less
benlavery  ttys005                   Mon Aug 31 09:58   still logged in
benlavery  ttys005  fe80::105e:6b27:29ff:d967%en0 Mon Aug 31 09:14 - 09:36  (00:22)
benlavery  ttys005  fe80::105e:6b27:29ff:d967%en0 Mon Aug 31 09:12 - 09:14  (00:01)
```

You can see when the user logged in and when they logged out—or if they are still logged in.

Comment: You can also use the `w` command.

Answer (score 1):

To find how much time you have been logged in, run this command from the original login shell:

```
ps -o etime= -p $$
```

Comment: To see your parent shells, use `ps ao etime`. This does not answer for any user, however.